# Как поставить картинку на задний фон label

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qlabel

Хочу сделать задний фон в `label` картинкой, но не знаю как это сделать.

Хотелось бы, чтобы картинка менялась каждый час (вообще не важен промежуток времени, я по аналогии смогу сделать так как я планирую).

В коде есть комментарий - это как раз один из вариантов моей попытки вставить картинку и он не получился.

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 
 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
        self._6_10 = [
            "Доброе утро", 
            "Удачного дня",
            "Пусть ваш день будет прекрасным",
            'Ой, новый день!',
        ]
        self._10_13 = [
            "Хорошей работы",
            'Здравствуйте',
        ]
        self._13_17 = [
            'Вот и пол дня прошло',
        ]
        self._17_21 = [
            'Вечер',
            'День подходит к концу',
        ]
        self._21_23 = [
            'Доброй ночи',
            'Спокойной ночи',
            'Добрых снов',
        ]
        self._23_2 = [
            'Не спиться? Тогда я буду с тобой',
        ]
        self._2_6 = [
            'Не спиться? Тогда я буду с тобой',
        ]
        hh_mm = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm')

        
        if '06:00' <= hh_mm < '10:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._6_10))
        elif '10:00' <= hh_mm < '13:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._10_13))
        elif '13:00' <= hh_mm < '17:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._13_17))
        elif '17:00' <= hh_mm < '21.00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._17_21))
        elif '21:00' <= hh_mm < '23:30':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._21_23))
        elif '02:00' <= hh_mm < '06:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._2_6))
        else:
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._23_2))


    def initUI(self):
        self.resize(300, 300)
        
        self.label = QLabel(self)                    
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)

        #self.label.setStyleSheet('background-image:url("111.jpg")')


        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")
        self.label.setFont(font)

        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Не отображается картинка? Или что не получается?

Comment: @Александр картинки вообще нет. Не получается вставить картинку

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь к картинке.

Comment: @Александр не получилось

Comment: Картинка точно JPEG? Название файла проверьте.

Comment: И синтаксис CSS не нарушайте "background-image : url(image.png);"

Comment: В конце нет точки с запятой и путь к файлу без кавычек.

Comment: self.label.setStyleSheet('background-image: url(C:\Users\Леонид Петровский\Desktop\814\111.jpg);') вот строчка, но не получается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127997/discussion-between-gidra-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *
 
 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        
        self.initUI()
        
        self._6_10 = [
            "Доброе утро", 
            "Удачного дня",
            "Пусть ваш день будет прекрасным",
            'Ой, новый день!',
        ]
        self._10_13 = [
            "Хорошей работы",
            'Здравствуйте',
        ]
        self._13_17 = [
            'Вот и пол дня прошло',
        ]
        self._17_21 = [
            'Вечер',
            'День подходит к концу',
        ]
        self._21_23 = [
            'Доброй ночи',
            'Спокойной ночи',
            'Добрых снов',
        ]
        self._23_2 = [
            'Не спиться? Тогда я буду с тобой',
        ]
        self._2_6 = [
            'Не спиться? Тогда я буду с тобой',
        ]
        hh_mm = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm')

        
        if '06:00' <= hh_mm < '10:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._6_10))
        elif '10:00' <= hh_mm < '13:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._10_13))
        elif '13:00' <= hh_mm < '17:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._13_17))
        elif '17:00' <= hh_mm < '21.00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._17_21))
        elif '21:00' <= hh_mm < '23:30':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._21_23))
        elif '02:00' <= hh_mm < '06:00':
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._2_6))
        else:
            self.label.setText(random.choice(self._23_2))


    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel(self)                    
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        vbox2 = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        vbox2.addWidget(self.label, alignment=Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        vbox.addWidget(self.widget) 


qss = """
#widget {
    border-image: url(rio.jpg) 0 0 0 0  ; 
}
QLabel {
    border-image: url(boy2.jpg) 0 0 0 0  ;
    min-width: 605px;
    min-height: 150px;    
    color: red;
    font-size:25px;
    }
"""     
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(630, 650)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**boy2.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**rio.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Gidra что не так?

Comment: а какая у вас версия python? просто я ставлю название картинки и она не появляется (файл python и картинка находятся в одном файле ). может это я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @Gidra Python 3.7.3

Comment: у меня 3.9.6 . это может быть причиной того что не работает?

Comment: @Gidra мой пример у вас не работает? О Python  3.9.6 ничего сказать не могу.

Comment: к сожалению нет

Comment: @Gidra а если поставить другие картинки не .jpg. a ,png ?

Comment: а вот с .png все работает

Comment: @Gidra где-то такое уже обсуждали, поищите в постах. 
Речь шла об отсутствии чего-то похожего на `qjpeg.dll` 
или отсутствия доступа не помню. 
Проверьте наличия у вас 
`...PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll`

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


# Отловить ошибки в слотах PyQt5
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    import traceback
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))
    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Critical error!', text)
    quit()
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions


class Informer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = {"morning": {"time": "2:57", "image-url": "Images/Morning.jpg"},
                "evening": {"time": "2:58", "image-url": "Images/Evening.jpg"}
        }

        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle("Информер")

        self.initUI()

        self.timer=QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_label_image)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        datetime = QDateTime.currentDateTime()

    def initUI(self):
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setFamily("Century Gothic")

        self.label_image = QLabel(self)
        self.label_image.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop)
        self.label_image.setFixedSize(self.width(), self.height())

        self.label_image.setFont(font)

    def update_label_image(self):
        time = QTime.currentTime()
        #(time.toString('h:m'))
        time_now = time.toString('h:m')
        if time_now == self.data["morning"]["time"]:
            url_image = self.data["morning"]["image-url"]
            self.label_image.setStyleSheet(f"background-image: url({url_image});")
        elif time_now == self.data["evening"]["time"]:
            url_image = self.data["evening"]["image-url"]
            self.label_image.setStyleSheet(f"background-image: url({url_image});")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    informer = Informer()
    informer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: Morning]

[image: Evening]

Comment: Текст который будет отображаться поверх картинки, тоже можете добавить в словарь self.data.

Comment: Ну а логику утро, день или вечер вы знаете как организовать.